# NestJS Problems with StreamableFile, don't get a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

When trying to send a response within a promise with

```js
(onrejected) => {
          return res.send(
            this.visualization.loadJsonData(
              'src/data/Softwarecomponent/Chromium Sample Analysis.json',
            ),
          );
        },
```

my StreamableFile Object won't get serialized as a JSON Object. I just get a bunch of information. I am not sure why this happen

controller file:

```js
  @Get()
  findSofwareComponentByProject(
    @Query('project') project: any,
    @Headers('API_KEY') apiKey: string,
    @Res() res: Response,
  ) {
    // throw new DataNotFoundException();
    const data = this.visualization.findSoftwareComponentByProject(
      apiKey,
      project,
    );

    data
      .then(
        (onfulfill) => {
          console.log('fullfilled 1');
        },
        (onrejected) => {
          return res.send(
            this.visualization.loadJsonData(
              'src/data/Softwarecomponent/Chromium Sample Analysis.json',
            ),
          );
        },
      )
      .catch((err) => console.log('Something is not working', err));

    return data;
  }
```

service file:
visualization.service.ts

```js
// Testing method to return JSON data
  loadJsonData(path: string) {
    const file = createReadStream(join(process.cwd(), path));
    return new StreamableFile(file);
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't `res.send(StreamableFile)`. The `StreamableFile` class is so you can return a stream and Nest will handle calling `stream.pipe(res)` for you. If you do want to use `res` directly, then do `new StreamableFile().getStream().pipe(res)`